# Spelling "web development" with/without hyphen

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

I'm trying to check the correctness of translation of some university courses from my native language to English... Is it correct to spell "web development" with hyphen?

I'm quite sure that "Web Development" is correct. Is "Ruby on Rails Web-development" correct, too?

While I remember coming across "web-..." in adjectives (for example, "web-based"), I don't remember any cases of spelling "web" with hyphen in nouns...

Comment: I think your instinct is correct in this case. "Ruby on Rails Web Development" is "more correct" than "...Web-development."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-development is incorrect.
Hyphenated adjectives are used when they qualify a noun.
like Web-based Frameworks

Web Development has evolved to be an umbrella term and hence should be treated as a non hyphenated noun